# Disable the link on certain pages

Tags: exclude, wp-list-pages

I currently have a site with two levels of navigation. I am styling the wp_list_pages() list to act as my navigation.

I would like to disable the link on some pages which have children (not exclude) so that I can hover over them to display the drop down navigation but I can't click on them.

Does anyone know of such a method or parameter I could add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go to the wordpress menu and make the target of the link a #. If the user clicks on it, they are taken to the top of the page where they probably are anyway since they're using the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a plugin that gives you the option to remove the link (it removes the URL and replaces it with a #) of parent-items from your wp_list_pages menu: [wp_list_pages tweaks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-list-pages-tweaks/).
It also adds two other options, give the parent-item an `is-parent` class & copy the parent-item into the submenu.